# Entity framework LINQ MVC API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am wondering how to return a single row with the newest date but I get errors on implicit conversion

```
var punum = db.OrdNumbers
               .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreateDate)
               .FirstOrDefault();

        return new OrdNumberDTO() { orderNum = punum.orderNum, CreateDate = punum.CreateDate};
```

// Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'ProduceService.Models.OrdNumberDTO' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Compare the return type of your method with `OrdNumberDTO` -- clearly they are not the same type.

Comment: As krik woll said , you should compare the return type of your method with OrdNumberDTO. In addition, you should check the punum, because it could be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you method expects IEnumerable, not single object, as a result,